# How can I embed a job on my own website?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

Previously, I was able to generate a JavaScript snippet to embed the <kbd>Apply Now</kbd> button on my own website. Now I cannot find how to do that.

Is this still possible? I could not find anything in the talent back-office.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This feature was deprecated - it had low usage and complex code that made it hard to improve our apply form.

Comment: No alternative/similar feature planned?

Comment: @CalvT Not currently.